# NSLocale.current.language returning the wrong value

Tags: ios, swift, translation, nslocale

When I change my language in iPhone settings it isn't reflected in NSLocale.current.language.

Is this because my app does not support Spanish? I would expect it to be reflected regardless. Ultimately I'm trying to get the ISO 639-1 (2-digit) region code for the users preferred language.

Code:

```
guard var preferredLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages.first else { return }

for language in NSLocale.preferredLanguages {
    print("preferredLanguage: \(language)")
}

print("languageCode: \(NSLocale.current.languageCode)")
print("regionCode: \(NSLocale.current.regionCode)")
```

Output:

```
preferredLanguage: es-US
preferredLanguage: haw-US
preferredLanguage: en-US
languageCode: Optional("en")
regionCode: Optional("US")
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. From the output I see your preferred language is "es-US". What did you change it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since iOS 11, `NSLocale.current` can only return languages supported by your app.

More info can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678964/173623

https://jaanus.com/ios-11-changes-localized-date-handling/

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't seen that it had changed in iOS 11. I wish they would change the functionality behind the scenes like that.

Comment: They don't want to bore us with the "little details" :)