# Date Formatter is returning nil in ios prior 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, ios11

I am trying to execute following code in ios 10 and 11. In ios 11 the code is working fine but in ios 10 the date formatter returns nil value.

```
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
       formatter.dateFormat = @"HHmm";
     NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:time];

    formatter.dateFormat =@"hh:mm a";
    NSString *strDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is "time" value ?

Comment: 1530,2240 likewise.

Comment: Please check this answer: [NSDateFormatter and current language in iOS11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46205763/nsdateformatter-and-current-language-in-ios11)

Comment: Is the iOS 10 device setup to use 12-hour time and the iOS 11 device setup to use 24-hour time? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feechur

Comment: Indeed it was issue of 12-hour time & 24-hour time. Solved it by setting   LocaleIdentifier.