# NSLocale.currentLocale returning wrong locale, Canada (English) instead of Canada (French)

Tags: ios, internationalization, locale, nsnumberformatter, nslocale

A user reported some internalization problems with my app when it came to using periods vs commas for the decimal separator. When I test it with US Region (periods) and with Germany Region (commas) everything works fine.

I got him to send me a screenshot of his Language & Region settings in his main Settings app and his Region is set to Canada and he has two languages installed: French and English, but with French first. His phone is clearly set to use the French language primarily:

[image]

Additionally, the formatting examples at the bottom of his screenshot CLEARLY show that the system should be using a comma as the decimal separator.

When he tries to enter numbers into one of the fields in my app, his keyboard clearly shows a comma and he's able to enter the value with a comma, but when I try to process the value entered my formatter isn't getting the right value because the formatter's locale is apparently wrong.

When I'm setting up my number formatters, I'm using the system's locale like this:

```
self.simpleNumberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
self.simpleNumberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
self.simpleNumberFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
```

When I checked what the `[NSLocale currentLocale]` was returning, I found out that it is returning `en_CA` which is English Canada when it should be giving me `fr_CA` because the user has clearly requested French as their primary.

Why is the system reporting `en_CA` instead of `fr_CA`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you include a full French localization with your app? Is this iOS 11?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46205763/nsdateformatter-and-current-language-in-ios11

Comment: @rmaddy No, I haven't done any localization with my app, so it is English only at the moment. I'll read that related link, thanks.