# DateFormatter returning string with incorrect language

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to show a formatted date at my device's language but it keeps showing in English (even though the device is set to Portuguese).

At my ViewController I created a date:

```
let todaysDate: Date = Date()
```

And I call this function (that it's an extension of Date):

```
func getFullDate() -> String {
    let dateFormatter  = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"
    dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar.current
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
    return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
}
```

The output is always in English:

```
08 March 2019
```

I also checked if the Locale.current is correct in the terminal and I got:

```
▿ en_BR (current)
```

I don't want to define the language hardcoded because I want to support other languages, but it's not working. Could you please give me any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: Your locale shows that it is set to English (that's what the `en` part means).

Comment: Really? But my device is in Portuguese and the region is also set to Portuguese. Am I missing anything?

Comment: If your app is only localized in English then this is expected.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46205763/nsdateformatter-and-current-language-in-ios11

Comment: Are you testing it on  a simulator or an actual device?

Comment: I actually tested on both and they presented the same behavior

Comment: As the link rmaddy posted the behaviour  changed in iOS11 and later

Comment: @dahiya_boy The timezone is irrelevant. That won't change the format or the language.

Comment: It was exactly what @rmaddy pointed out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for your help!

I just found out that I only had Localized strings for English and as rmaddy pointed out in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46205763/nsdateformatter-and-current-language-in-ios11) with iOS 11 I also need to have a Localized string file for the language I want to support (in my case Portuguese).

So I just added support for Portuguese at Language localization section and now it's working correctly! :D

[image: Localization]

Answer (score 6):

```
func portugueseFormattedEn_US -> String {
        Formatter.date.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        Formatter.date.locale   = Locale(identifier: “pt-PT”)
        Formatter.date.timeZone = .current
        Formatter.date.dateFormat = "dd/M/yyyy, H:mm"
        return Formatter.date.string(from: self)
    }
```

in  "Locale(identntfier: “pt-PT”)" you have to pass exact identifier which you want and need to set language as well. [image: in Info you have to set your exact languahe as well]

Comment: This answer will be more correct if you simply remove the line that sets the formatter's locale. It will default to the user's locale.

Comment: is it `func` or `var`?

Comment: It's a function.

Answer (score 4):

**As I Understand your question. You want to change the date format with the current device language.**

*Set Locale as your preferred language*

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
formatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: Locale.preferredLanguages.first!)
formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("ddMMMMyyyy HH:mm")
let stringDate = formatter.string(from: Date())

print(stringDate)
```

**Output:- Show date with current device language.**

08 de março de 2019 10:54

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the app displaying the ***dates in Portuguese***,

1. Add an empty `Strings.strings` file
2. In projects settings, add the **Portuguese** localization
3. Although the strings file is empty, the app will become localized in
   **Portuguese** so by changing the language, in Settings, to **Portuguese**