# NSLocale.currentLocale in iOS always returns en_US. Does not return the language of iPad

Tags: ios, nslocale

I am using the following code:

```
NSLocale *locale = NSLocale.currentLocale;
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSString *langaugeCode =[locale objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];
```

and the language code always comes back to be en_US even if I switch the language of my iPad. Any suggestions of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [NSDateFormatter and current language in iOS11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46205763/nsdateformatter-and-current-language-in-ios11).

Comment: Try this code 'NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] firstObject];
'